# Unable to parse into JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, unicode

I have search every where but no one stated this error before.

The obj will return a unicode object but it will return the following error

```
Exception Type: AttributeError  
Exception Value:'unicode' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

It works if I hard code the result from the response.
CustomerAccount.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

*check login*

```
 return user
```

api.py

```
result = CustomerAccount.login(username, password)  
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
```

views.py

```
import urllib2  
import json

res = urllib2.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login?username=admin&password=admin").read()  
obj = json.loads(res)
print obj[0].pk
```

Result of print obj:

> [{"pk": 1, "model": "auth.user", "fields": {"username": "admin", "first_name": "Admin", "last_name": "admin", "is_active": true, "is_superuser": true, "is_staff": true, "last_login": "2013-05-29T08:08:43.859Z", "groups": [], "user_permissions": [], "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$10000$1HdCOPgsoXvx$8jjOpTFVcVAtUshpjJDPEGs/TRq7jeJ2T/2i55FIPeM=", "email": "admin@admin.com", "date_joined": "2013-05-15T07:59:30Z"}}]

Comment: You're looking up a dictionary, shouldn't it be `print obj[0]['pk']`?

Answer (score 3):

You got your types wrong:

- `obj` is a `list`
- `obj[0]` is a `dict`
- a `dict` has no `pk` attribute, however you can retrieve the value for key `"pk"` with: `obj[0]['pk']`

Comment: Tried print obj[0]['pk'] and I have this error  
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: string indices must be integers

Comment: tried obj[0].get('pk') this is the following error
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: It seems like obj is a list of string when i do print obj[0] it will give me the first char of the string.

Comment: this is not a proper (but valid if javascript) json object for python. btw. You're mixing in javascript datatypes, `true` unquoted. Python will spazz on this.

Comment: Tried the changing the true to True but no different. It is still unicode object.

Comment: @limelights, you got the answer. The OP is encoding in JSON *twice*, so that what he gets out of `json.loads()` is a unicode string, not a list of dicts.

Comment: Omg THANKS! what a careless mistake which i spend almost 12hrs figuring it out. Thanks Iserni and all =)

Answer (score 2):

You say you get

```
Exception Value:'unicode' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

when retrieving `obj[0].pk` . If it was a data type error, you would get `'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'` instead.

So the problem is that your `obj[0]` is not a `dict` as you expect, or a `list`, but it is a **unicode string**.

As per comments, this is what happens:

1. You generate the JSON object server side.
2. JSON-encode it. You now have a **unicode string**.
3. JSON-encode it *again*. Now you have a unicode string as a JSON object.
4. Retrieve it from the URL.
5. Decode it **once**. You now have the **unicode string** which encodes the object.
6. Extract `pk` from the unicode string... and you can't do that.

A quick fix would be to decode the object twice. The real fix is detect where the double encoding takes place and prevent that from happening.

The telltale that *should* have told me what had happened was this:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": ...
```

If that had been a **Python** object (instead of a JSON encoding), it would have been:

```
[{u'pk': 1, u'model': ...
```

Comment: Hardcoding works but if i retrieve it from the url it does not work.

Comment: Yes, I saw it on re-reading your question and updated the answer.

Comment: This is the output of the URL return
"[{\"pk\": 1, \"model\": \"auth.user\", \"fields\": {\"username\": \"admin\", \"first_name\": \"Admin\", \"last_name\": \"admin\", \"is_active\": true, \"is_superuser\": true, \"is_staff\": true, \"last_login\": \"2013-05-29T08:08:43.859Z\", \"groups\": [], \"user_permissions\": [], \"password\": \"pbkdf2_sha256$10000$1HdCOPgsoXvx$8jjOpTFVcVAtUshpjJDPEGs/TRq7jeJ2T/2i55FIPeM=\", \"email\": \"admin@admin.com\", \"date_joined\": \"2013-05-15T07:59:30Z\"}}]"

Comment: It is a User object and was JSON.dumps into a http response.

Comment: How i dump it:

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")

Comment: Such output can't be parsed by JSON. It is an escaped string representation. `json.loads` tells me "ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 4...". What do you do with that string? Post the complete code.